# Ground truth robot position from Ignition Gazebo Sim to ROS 2

Tags: ros2, odometry, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress, ros-iron

Gazebo Sim 6.15 (Fortress), ROS 2 Iron.

I want to get "ground truth" robot position into ROS, so that I could use it to validate diff_drive odometry (combining it with IMU to detect wheel slip maybe etc.). Presumably as also Odometry frames so that I could write my own script to compare them and calculate drift or sth.

I have found references to some "p3d" plugin, but only from around 2015 and before, so presumably they apply to Gazebo Classic. Gazebo Sim website has a checkmark next to "JointStatePublisher" plugin, but I have utterly failed to find any information about it, and any search is littered with results about the ROS plugin with same name and Gazebo Classic :(.

What is the standard approach for eg comparing simulated wheel odometry with actual position in simulation?

Comment: Haven't tried in ros2 yet, but in ros1 it was published on a topic: `rostopic echo /gazebo/model_states`